# Trying to Install TFS 2010 - SQL Server Reporting Services Problem

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, installation

Hoping someone here can help. Trying to install SQL Server Reporting Services to use for TFS 2010 and i'm having issues. I'm going directly from the TFS Install Guide. At first i had issues getting report services working so i decided just to completely uninstall SQL Server and reinstall.

When i try to connect to:
http://MyServer:80/Reports i get the follwing error:
User 'MyServer/Admin' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

When i try to connect to http://MyServer/ReportServer i get the following error:
The permissions granted to user 'MyServer\Admin' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Except for the error message the rest of the page is pretty much blank.

Every time i try to connect to either i get a login dialg and i type in the username/password for the machine admin/sql server sysadmin.

Trying to google you see all kinds of people having the issue and every person seems the have a unique solution that doesn't work. For example. I've tried to run IE in admin privileges and it doesn't help.

I even tried to run the report service process under the adminstrator just to see if that would help and no luck.

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise
DB: Sql Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise

Comment: I had problems installing sharepoint 2010 (which is no longer on my system) and i've had nothing but problems since then.

Answer (score 0):

When you are prompted to login are what credentials are you using? Can you try logging in w/ an account that has administrator privileges on the machine?

Should be:
Username: DOMAIN\USER
Password: Password

Comment: account i'm logging in with has both admin privldeges of the machine and is also the sysadmin of the database